# TSQL - Query XML and merge root nodes

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing, xquery

I'm trying to build up an XML in the following format (our provider has no XSD):

```
<Submission>
<Office Account="ACCOUNT">
    <schedule submissionPeriod="" areaOfLaw="" scheduleNum="abc">
        <outcome matterType="A:B">
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">DATA</outcomeItem>
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">DATA</outcomeItem>
        </outcome>
        <outcome matterType="C:D">
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">DATA</outcomeItem>
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">DATA</outcomeItem>
        </outcome>
    </schedule>
    <schedule submissionPeriod="" areaOfLaw="" scheduleNum="def">
        <outcome matterType="E:F">
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">DATA</outcomeItem>
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">DATA</outcomeItem>
        </outcome>
    </schedule>
</Office>
<Office Account="ACCOUNT2">
    <schedule submissionPeriod="" areaOfLaw="" scheduleNum="ghi">
        <outcome matterType="A:B">
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">DATA</outcomeItem>
            <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">DATA</outcomeItem>
        </outcome>
    </schedule>
</Office>
```

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT  supplier_no AS 'Office/@Account' ,
    UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()), 3)) + '-' + DATENAME(YYYY,
                                                          GETDATE()) AS 'Office/schedule/@submissionPeriod' ,
    'LEGAL HELP' AS 'Office/schedule/@areaOfLaw' ,
    supplier_no + '/CIVIL' AS 'Office/schedule/@scheduleNum' ,
    ClaimsTable.mattype1_code + ':' + ClaimsTable.mattype2_code AS 'Office/schedule/outcome/@matterType' , 
    (SELECT * FROM ( 

                  SELECT 'CASE_START_DATE' AS 'outcomeItem/@Name', 'DATA' AS 'outcomeItem' UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'CASE_ID' AS 'outcomeItem/@Name',  'DATA' AS 'outcomeItem'

                ) OutcomeItems FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS 'Office/schedule/outcome'

FROM    ContractsTable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimsTable ON ContractsTable.contract_no = ClaimsTable.contract_no
WHERE   ClaimsTable.compno = 2
    AND ClaimsTable.submitted_period = 0
FOR     XML PATH('Submission') ,
        TYPE
```

Which is producing the following XML

```
<Submission>
  <Office Account="MHESUPPLIE">
<schedule submissionPeriod="FEB-2013" areaOfLaw="LEGAL HELP" scheduleNum="MHESUPPLIE/CIVIL">
  <outcome matterType="MHNS:MOUT">
    <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">13/02/2013</outcomeItem>
    <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">001</outcomeItem>
  </outcome>
</schedule>
  </Office>
</Submission>
<Submission>
  <Office Account="MHESUPPLIE">
<schedule submissionPeriod="FEB-2013" areaOfLaw="LEGAL HELP" scheduleNum="MHESUPPLIE/CIVIL">
  <outcome matterType="MHAS:MGUA">
    <outcomeItem Name="CASE_START_DATE">14/02/2013</outcomeItem>
    <outcomeItem Name="CASE_ID">001</outcomeItem>
  </outcome>
</schedule>
  </Office>
</Submission>
```

Obviously the output XML has multiple root nodes which is invalid. I'm trying to find a way to combine the result together to achieve the XML type I need. Are there any ideas on how this can be achieved on SQL Server 2005+?

Comment: What happens if you use `FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Submission')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified you query a little. Assume your query looks like this:

```
SELECT STR(X) AS [office/schedule]
FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) AS CompleQuery(x)
FOR XML PATH('Submission'),TYPE;
```

That produces:

```
<Submission><office><schedule> 1</schedule></office></Submission><Submission><office><schedule> 2</schedule></office></Submission>
```

To get both office tags into one submission use this instead:

```
SELECT (
SELECT STR(X) AS [office/schedule]
FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) AS CompleQuery(x)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('Submission'),TYPE;
```

So, change `PATH('Submission')` to `PATH('')` in your query and then wrap it into another `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH('Submission'),TYPE;`

Result:

```
<Submission><office><schedule> 1</schedule></office><office><schedule> 2</schedule></office></Submission>
```